# Can I attach a trailer to a Bixi bicycle?

Tags: sharing-scheme

Do the bikes used by the [Bixi](http://www.bixisystem.com/what-we-do/the-bike/) bike sharing system, in cities like [London](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/roadusers/cycling/14808.aspx), [Boston](http://www.thehubway.com) and [New York](http://citibikenyc.com), accept trailers like [Trail-a-bikes](http://www.trail-a-bike.com) and [Tag-a-longs](http://www.tagalong.com)?

Comment: Generally, the "trail-a-bike" style trailers attach via the seatpost, and it appears the Bixi bikes have a normal seatpost style. I'd expect that kind of trailer to work, but I have no actual experience.

Comment: @freiheit: Looking more closely, it seems (I haven't tried, but I assume) that the seats can't be completly removed from Bixi bikes, so the question may be: (1) are there standard seat post attachments for trail-a-bikes that clamp on (rather than requiring removal of the post) and (2) is attaching a trailer to a Hubway/Barclays/citi-bike allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many trailers attach via a hitch on the rear axle of the bicycle. Since bike share bikes use proprietary fittings to reduce theft, it would not be possible to install one of these on a bike-share bike.

The trailers you are asking about appear to attach to a seat post. Bike share bikes always have adjustable (but not removable) seat posts. You should have no problem adjusting the post and installing one of these seats.

You may find it's not worth your effort attaching and detaching a trailer when you're likely to be only using the bike for a half hour at a time.